# How to write CMakeLists in android studio to call functions from my c++project (JNI)

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, java-native-interface

I am new for Android Studio. I have built a c++ project within which has `.cc` and `.h` files. But I want to perform them by an app to be developed by Android Studio 2.2. I've searched tutorial like [Add C and C++ Code to Your Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) to learn how to write `CMakeLists.txt`.

And this is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(src/main/include/)

add_library(
             native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
              )
add_library(
             UnitTest
             STATIC
             src/main/cpp/UnitTest.cc
              )
add_library(
             CaffeEva
             STATIC
             src/main/cpp/CaffeEva.cc
              )
add_library(
             CaffeEvaWrapper
             STATIC
             src/main/cpp/CaffeEvaWrapper.cc
              )
add_library(
             BmpImgIO
             STATIC
             src/main/cpp/BmpImgIO.cc
              )
add_library(
            BlasWrapper
             STATIC
             src/main/cpp/BlasWrapper.cc
              )
add_library(
             CaffePara
             STATIC
             src/main/cpp/CaffePara.cc
              )

find_library(  
              log-lib

              log )

target_link_libraries(  
                       native-lib
                        UnitTest
                        CaffeEva
                        CaffeEvaWrapper
                        BmpImgIO
                        BlasWrapper
                        CaffePara 
                       ${log-lib} )
```

to compile my source `.cc` files and `.h` files.

My purpose is to call function `UnitTest::UT_CaffeEvaWrapper();` which is involved in `UnitTest.cc` by JNI to dispose its results on my android phone.

Even though I use the demo `HellpJNI` provided by google with some changes like adding my own files to it, it shows error:

```
Unfortunately, Q_CNN has stopped.
```

But make build is OK without any errors. I don't know how to make it. So is there anyone who can help me? Specified tutorials is also OK. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've debugged my program step by step.And I find that It's the wrong files directory path that causes this problem.My files folder is:

const std::string kClsNameFilePath = "/home/zz/AndroidStudioProjects/Q_CNN/app/src/main/assets/Cls.Names/class_names.txt";
  const std::string kImgLablFilePath = "/home/zz/AndroidStudioProjects/Q_CNN/app/src/main/assets/Cls.Names/image_labels.txt";
  const std::string kBmpFilePath = "/home/zz/AndroidStudioProjects/Q_CNN/app/src/main/assets/Bmp.Files/ILSVRC2012_val_00000009.BMP";

but when I debug,I find that

FILE* inFile = fopen(filePath.c_str(), "r");

the pointer inFile is null.I don't know how to solve this.

Finally,I solved this by putting my files under my phone!And the following steps are to visit your sdcard!Also you should open authority by adding lines in AndroidManifest.xml